# Why does typeof NaN return 'number'?

Tags: javascript, nan

Just out of curiosity.

It doesn't seem very logical that `typeof NaN` is number. Just like `NaN === NaN` or `NaN == NaN` returning false, by the way. Is this one of the peculiarities of JavaScript, or would there be a reason for this?

Edit: thanks for your answers. It's not an easy thing to get ones head around though. Reading answers and the wiki I understood more, but still, a sentence like

> A comparison with a `NaN` always returns an unordered result even when comparing with itself. The comparison predicates are either signaling or non-signaling, the signaling versions signal an invalid exception for such comparisons. The equality and inequality predicates are non-signaling so `x = x` returning false can be used to test if x is a quiet `NaN`.

just keeps my head spinning. If someone can translate this in human (as opposed to, say, mathematician) readable language, I would be grateful.

[**addendum 2023/06**] I've create a small module for checking the type of anything in ES. It may be helpful, check it [@GitHub](https://github.com/KooiInc/typeofAnything)

Comment: +1: "NaN is a number but is not-a-number. Hum... what ?!"

Comment: For extra fun; (NaN !== NaN) == true

Comment: Even more fun (but understandable coming to think of it, isNaN returns a boolean): isNaN(parseInt('nodice')) === isNaN(parseInt('someOtherNaN')) === true;

Comment: parseInt("1A") is 1 but the string itself isNaN - what is the string you are parsing?

Comment: If using jQuery, I prefer `isNumeric` over checking the type:
`$.isNumeric(NaN);`  returns false, where as `$.type(NaN);`, returns number. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Comment: My code wasn't working - stepping into debugger - and yes... ```typeof NaN``` is ```"number"``` *(need to add extra condition)*

Comment: As professional mathematician I must say that sentence has little in common with precise language of maths.

Comment: I hate to say it, but these nonsensical anomalies (which are more common than you'd want to believe) are among many reasons why the Javascript language is an utter dumpster fire.  But, what can you expect from a language where you have to plaster 'use strict' over every file to get any sort of language-level code quality enforcement?.

Comment: What else colud be? if you're not human, that's also a condition of a human...being ...not-a-human??? I'm sorry

Comment: @Ron So: *Not a Number equals Number* is what you say?

Comment: Yhea the Not a Number being a number is really a nice funny Joke xD
I would suggest to use the term Unknown Number instead

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It means Not a Number. It is not a peculiarity of javascript but common computer science principle.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN:

> There are three kinds of operation
>   which return NaN:
>
> Operations with a NaN as at least one operand
>
> Indeterminate forms
>
> - The divisions 0/0, ∞/∞, ∞/−∞, −∞/∞, and −∞/−∞
> - The multiplications 0×∞ and 0×−∞
> - The power 1^∞
> - The additions ∞ + (−∞), (−∞) + ∞ and equivalent subtractions.
>
> Real operations with complex results:
>
> - The square root of a negative number
> - The logarithm of a negative number
> - The tangent of an odd multiple of 90 degrees (or π/2 radians)
> - The inverse sine or cosine of a number which is less than −1 or
>     greater than +1.

All these values may not be the same. A simple test for a NaN is to test `value == value` is false.

Comment: An even simpler test is `isNaN(value)`

Comment: @Alsciende it's not equivalent though.  `isNaN(undefined)` returns `true`, but `undefined == undefined` is also true.  Same goes for all other non-number types except `null`.

Comment: In other words, `value !== value` is probably the shortest way to test if `value` is truly `NaN`.

Comment: It looks like you are right, @Andy. Now that's a peculiarity.

Comment: The phrase "these values may not be the same" has no meaning, because those values do not exist.

Answer (score 137):

Well, it may seem a little strange that something called "not a number" is considered a number, but `NaN` is still a numeric *type*, despite that fact :-)

`NaN` just means the specific value cannot be represented within the limitations of the numeric type (although that could be said for all numbers that have to be rounded to fit, but `NaN` is a special case).

A specific `NaN` is not considered equal to another `NaN` because they may be different values. However, `NaN` is still a number type, just like 2718 or 31415.

---

As to your updated question to explain in layman's terms:

> A comparison with a NaN always returns an unordered result even when comparing with itself. The comparison predicates are either signalling or non-signalling, the signalling versions signal an invalid exception for such comparisons. The equality and inequality predicates are non-signalling so x = x returning false can be used to test if x is a quiet NaN.

All this means is (broken down into parts):

> A comparison with a NaN always returns an unordered result even when comparing with itself.

Basically, a `NaN` is not equal to any other number, including another `NaN`, and even including *itself*.

> The comparison predicates are either signalling or non-signalling, the signalling versions signal an invalid exception for such comparisons.

Attempting to do comparison (less than, greater than, and so on) operations between a `NaN` and another number can either result in an exception being thrown (signalling) or just getting false as the result (non-signalling or quiet).

> The equality and inequality predicates are non-signalling so x = x returning false can be used to test if x is a quiet NaN.

Tests for equality (equal to, not equal to) are never signalling so using them will not cause an exception. If you have a regular number `x`, then `x == x` will always be true. If `x` is a `NaN`, then `x == x` will always be false. It's giving you a way to detect `NaN` easily (quietly).

Comment: good explanation, although I disagree in the last two sentences: a better way to check if x is a NaN is using isNaN() function

Comment: @DominicRodger here's how I think about it: `typeof a === 'number'` means "a is stored internally as an IEEE 754 float"

Comment: Why does `Infinity === Infinity` return `true` if an `Infinity` can be produced by different values: 1.0 / 0.0 or 2.0 / 0.0?

Comment: @Hashem, quite likely because they're considered the same infinity. Treating division as repeated subtraction, it makes no difference whether you start at two or one, it's the same number of steps required to reach (or, more accurately, *not* reach) zero. I understand math gurus do *have* different classes of infinity but (1) I suspect `1/0` and `2/0` lay in the same class and (2) there's only one class of infinity in IEEE754 (other than `+/-` of course).

Comment: What is "unordered result"?

Comment: Actually the comparison `NaN < 0` evaluates to `false`!

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: as per a C11 footnote, `IEC 60559 requires that the built-in relational operators raise the ‘‘invalid’’ floating-point exception if the operands compare unordered, as an error indicator for programs written without consideration of NaNs; the result in these cases is false.` I've also changed the erroneous statement in the answer re returning NaN - thanks for the heads-up, I can only assume I was drunk at the time I wrote that :-)

Comment: No worries, the design is so horribly confusing and inconsistent, no wonder.

Comment: "A specific NaN is not considered equal to another NaN because they may be different values" --- this very common "explanation" actually has no merit as there is no other value than 'NaN'.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev, I suspect you're misreading my explanation. There may well only be one NaN in the IEEE754 encoding scheme. However, there are an *infinite* number of *actual* numbers that NaN can refer to and it was these values I was referring to. For example, the square root of `-1`, the natural logarithm of `-42`, and `0 / 0` are *distinct* numbers in math, but will all appear as `NaN` in IEEE754.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to define these exceptional "actual numbers" in any meaningful way. In maths the log and the root of negatives can only be obtained by means of extension of reals to complex numbers, where they evaluate to multiple values, and `0/0` is not defined in any meaningful way, other than saying its "value" is the whole set of numbers.  And even if they were defined, `Math.log(-1) == Math.log(-1)` still evaluates to `false`. So not only there are no "actual numbers" other than `NaN` but even if there were, they were not used for comparison.

Comment: So why is **"two" * 2** of type number? it returns NaN, surely this can never represent a numberical number like in the above example

Comment: @SuperUberDuper, it's probably to do with the preferred type of the arguments given to the multiplication operator. ECMAScript states when applying `ToNumber` to a string, "If the grammar cannot interpret the string as an expansion of StringNumericLiteral, then the result of ToNumber is NaN." So, once `"two"` has been converted to `NaN` because of that, the multiplication rules in the standard take over: "If either operand is NaN, the result is NaN."

Comment: that really doesn't make sense at all, despite the background, it's just wrong

Comment: @MladenJanjetovic, not sure which bit you're claiming to be wrong (or whether it just *seems* wrong to you). If it's something in the answer, please let me know so I can fix or explain. If it's the behaviour of ECMAScript as per SuperUberDuper's comment, well, that's just lost in the general mish-mash of "all things wrong with ECMAScript" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Just wrong in general :) it just passes the scope of programming and common sense. The answer is great ;)

Answer (score 22):

The ECMAScript (JavaScript) standard specifies that `Numbers` are [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floats, which include `NaN` as a possible value.

> #### [ECMA 262 5e Section 4.3.19](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_4.htm#Section_4.3.19):   Number value
>
> primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value.

> #### [ECMA 262 5e Section 4.3.23](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_4.htm#Section_4.3.23):   NaN
>
> Number value that is a IEEE 754 "Not-a-Number" value.

> #### [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) on Wikipedia
>
> The IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic is a technical standard established by the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers and the most widely used standard for floating-point computation [...]
>
> The standard defines
>
> - *arithmetic formats*: sets of binary and decimal floating-point data, which consist of finite numbers (including signed zeros and subnormal numbers), infinities, and **special "not a number" values (NaNs)**
>
> [...]

Answer (score 9):

`typeof NaN` returns `'number'` because:

- ECMAScript spec says the Number type includes NaN:

  > [**4.3.20 Number type**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.20)
  >
  > set of all possible Number values including the special “Not-a-Number”
  >   (NaN) values, positive infinity, and negative infinity
- So `typeof` returns accordingly:

  > **[11.4.3 The typeof Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)**
  >
  > The production *UnaryExpression* : `typeof` *UnaryExpression* is
  >   evaluated as follows:
  >
  > 1. Let *val* be the result of evaluating *UnaryExpression*.
  > 2. If [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*val*) is [Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7), then
  >
  >    1. If [IsUnresolvableReference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7)(*val*) is **true**, return `"undefined"`.
  >    2. Let *val* be [GetValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)(*val*).
  > 3. Return a String determined by [Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8)(*val*) according to Table 20.
  >      ​
  >
  > ```
  >                 Table 20 — typeof Operator Results
  > ==================================================================
  > |        Type of val         |              Result               |
  > ==================================================================
  > | Undefined                  | "undefined"                       |
  > |----------------------------------------------------------------|
  > | Null                       | "object"                          |
  > |----------------------------------------------------------------|
  > | Boolean                    | "boolean"                         |
  > |----------------------------------------------------------------|
  > | Number                     | "number"                          |
  > |----------------------------------------------------------------|
  > | String                     | "string"                          |
  > |----------------------------------------------------------------|
  > | Object (native and does    | "object"                          |
  > | not implement [[Call]])    |                                   |
  > |----------------------------------------------------------------|
  > | Object (native or host and | "function"                        |
  > | does implement [[Call]])   |                                   |
  > |----------------------------------------------------------------|
  > | Object (host and does not  | Implementation-defined except may |
  > | implement [[Call]])        | not be "undefined", "boolean",    |
  > |                            | "number", or "string".            |
  > ------------------------------------------------------------------
  > ```

This behavior is in accordance with [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point):

> [**4.3.19 Number value**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19)
>
> primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary
>   format IEEE 754 value
>
> [**4.3.23 NaN**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23)
>
> number value that is a IEEE 754 “Not-a-Number” value
>
> [**8.5 The Number Type**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)
>
> The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 (that is, 2<sup>53</sup>−2<sup>64</sup>+3)
>   values, representing the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754
>   values as specified in the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point
>   Arithmetic, except that the 9007199254740990 (that is, 2<sup>53</sup>−2) distinct
>   “Not-a-Number” values of the IEEE Standard are represented in
>   ECMAScript as a single special *NaN* value. (Note that the *NaN* value
>   is produced by the program expression `NaN`.)

Answer (score 6):

`NaN != NaN` because they are not necessary the SAME non-number. Thus it makes a lot of sense...
Also why floats have both +0.00 and -0.00 that are not the same. Rounding may do that they are actually not zero.

As for typeof, that depends on the language. And most languages will say that NaN is a float, double or number depending on how they classify it... I know of no languages that will say this is an unknown type or null.

Comment: ehr, consider: var x = parseInt('no dice'), y = x; Now I would say that both NaN's are exactly the same? But no, x === y returns false too.

Comment: yes, but you cant be SURE, and thus they are not the same. It is the same logic as NULLable logic in database. Although many people think of them as the same as null pointers from other programming languages, they infact have a totally different semantics. They are "UNKNOWN" and thus one NULL value compared to another is always false. Doing calculations on a NULL value ends up with the result NULL. Try to view it from the perspective of the value being called UNKNOWN instead

Comment: As being of type `number`,  `NaN` is primitive, and hence uniquely determined by its value.

Answer (score 5):

NaN is a valid floating point value (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

and NaN === NaN is false because they're not necessarily the same non-number

Comment: Sorry but I have to say that's not a good way to think about it. "not necessarily the same non-number" does not mean they are *always* different and comparing them should yield false. It's best not to quantify NaN and just think of it as an oddity in our knowledge base.

Comment: So why all `Infinity`s somehow are identical? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

`NaN` stands for [Not a Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). It is a value of numeric data types (usually floating point types, but not always) that represents the result of an invalid operation such as dividing by zero.

Although its names says that it's not a number, the data type used to hold it is a numeric type. So in JavaScript, asking for the datatype of `NaN` will return `number` (as `alert(typeof(NaN))` clearly demonstrates).

Comment: Actually dividing by zero is evaluated to `Infinity` not `NaN`

Answer (score 3):

A better name for `NaN`, describing its meaning more precisely and less confusingly, would be a **numerical exception**. It is really another kind of exception object disguised as having primitive type (by the language design), where at the same it is not treated as primitive in its false self-comparison. Whence the confusion. And as long as the language "will not make its mind" to choose between *proper exception object* and *primitive numeral*, the confusion will stay.

The infamous non-equality of `NaN` to itself, both `==` and `===` is a manifestation of the confusing design forcing this exception object into being a primitive type. This breaks the fundamental principle that a **primitive is uniquely determined by its value**. If `NaN` is preferred to be seen as exception (of which there can be different kinds), then it should not be "sold" as primitive. And if it is wanted to be primitive, that principle must hold. As long as it is broken, as we have in JavaScript, and we can't really decide between the two, the confusion leading to unnecessary cognitive load for everyone involved will remain. Which, however, is really easy to fix by simply making the choice between the two:

- either make `NaN` a special exception object containing the useful information about how the exception arose, as opposed to throwing that information away as what is currently implemented, leading to harder-to-debug code;
- or make `NaN` an entity of the primitive type `number` (that could be less confusingly called "numeric"), in which case it should be equal to itself and cannot contain any other information; the latter is clearly an inferior choice.

The only conceivable advantage of forcing `NaN` into `number` type is being able to throw it back into any numerical expression. Which, however, makes it brittle choice, because the result of any numerical expression containing `NaN` will either be `NaN`, or leading to unpredictable results such as `NaN < 0` evaluating to `false`, i.e. returning `boolean` instead of keeping the exception.

And even if "things are the way they are", nothing prevents us from making that clear distinction for ourselves, to help make our code more predictable and easierly debuggable. In practice, that means identifying those exceptions and dealing with them as exceptions. Which, unfortunately, means more code but hopefully will be mitigated by tools such as TypeScript of Flowtype.

And then we have the messy [quiet vs noisy aka signalling `NaN` distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). Which really is about how exceptions are handled, not the exceptions themselves, and nothing different from other exceptions.

Similarly, `Infinity` and `+Infinity` are elements of *numeric type* arising in the [extension of the real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) but they are not real numbers. Mathematically, they can be represented by sequences of real numbers converging to either `+` or `-Infinity`.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript uses NaN to represent anything it encounters that can't be represented any other way by its specifications. It does not mean it is not a number. It's just the easiest way to describe the encounter. NaN means that it or an object that refers to it could not be represented in any other way by javascript. For all practical purposes, it is 'unknown'. Being 'unknown' it cannot tell you what it is nor even if it is itself. It is not even the object it is assigned to. It can only tell you what it is not, and not-ness or nothingness can only be described mathematically in a programming language. Since mathematics is about numbers, javascript represents nothingness as NaN. That doesn't mean it's not a number. It means we can't read it any other way that makes sense. That's why it can't even equal itself. Because it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because `NaN` is a property of the Number object in JS, It has nothing to do with it being a number.

Comment: Like every other object, Number can have any type of property. `Number.fu = "bar"; alert(typeof Number.fu);`

Comment: `NaN` is not the value stored in `Number.NaN`, whatever it might be. `NaN` is a primitive value of Number type. And additionally, the value of `Number.NaN` is `NaN`, but that's unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think of NAN is that its not a **known** number. Thats why NAN != NAN because each NAN value represents some unique unknown number. NANs are necessary because floating point numbers have a limited range of values. In some cases rounding occurs where the lower bits are lost which leads to what appears to be nonsense like 1.0/11*11 != 1.0. Really large values which are greater are NANs with infinity being a perfect example.

Given we only have ten fingers any attempt to show values greater than 10 are impossible, which means such values must be NANs because we have lost the true value of this greater than 10 value. The same is true of floating point values, where the value exceeds the limits of what can be held in a float.

Comment: Infinity is not represented by a NaN. Attempting to represent a number outside of the range would be rounded down (to max/-inf) or up (to min/+inf).

Answer (score 1):

NaN is still a numeric type, but it represents value that could not represent a valid number.

Answer (score 1):

Because NaN is a numeric data type.

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` is a number from a type point of view, but is not a normal number like 1, 2 or 329131. The name **"Not A Number"** refers to the fact that the value represented is special and is about the IEEE format spec domain, not javascript language domain.

Answer (score 1):

If using jQuery, I prefer `isNumeric` over checking the type:

```
console.log($.isNumeric(NaN));  // returns false
console.log($.type(NaN));       // returns number
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Comment: Thanks man. I had problems with `isNumber` from `util` package of Typescript. Good that we still use `jQuery` in our project so used your suggestion instead.

Comment: For the rec, `isNumber` from `util` of typescript also returns `true` for `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has only one numeric data type, which is the standard 64-bit double-precision float. Everything is a double. NaN is a special value of double, but it's a double nonetheless.

All that `parseInt` does is to "cast" your string into a numeric data type, so the result is *always* "number"; only if the original string wasn't parseable, its value will be NaN.

Answer (score 0):

We could argue that NaN is a special case object. In this case, NaN's object represents a number that makes no mathematical sense. There are some other special case objects in math like INFINITE and so on.

You can still do some calculations with it, but that will yield strange behaviours.

More info here: http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/javafloat.htm (java based, not javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You've got to love Javascript. It has some interesting little quirks.

http://wtfjs.com/page/13

Most of those quirks can be explained if you stop to work them out logically, or if you know a bit about number theory, but nevertheless they can still catch you out if you don't know about them.

By the way, I recommend reading the rest of http://wtfjs.com/ -- there's a lot more interesting quirks than this one to be found!

Answer (score 0):

The value NaN is really the Number.NaN hence when you ask if it is a number it will say yes. You did the correct thing by using the isNaN() call.

For information, NaN can also be returned by operations on Numbers that are not defined like divisions by zero or square root of a negative number.

Comment: In what sense it is "the value"? `NaN == Number.NaN` evaluates to `false`!

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev Have you read the thread? And have you tried if (parseInt("nan") == Number.NaN)? Also try != and see what it tells you.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the stupid `NaN==NaN` being `false`, it must have been a sadist who invented that to make everyone suffer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is very simple, just check the NaN constructor function and it will be Number constructor function:

```
NaN.__proto__
```

Comment: You might want to add more context around how the constructor function understanding helps when OP has given various examples of how they are unable to grasp the concept with NaN === NaN and NaN == NaN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

It is special value of Number type as POSITIVE_INFINITY

Why? By design

Answer (score -3):

### An example

Imagine We are converting a string to a number:

```
Number("string"); // returns NaN
```

We changed the data type to number but its value is not a number!

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of the question. `NaN` is of the *number* type. The question is asking why.

Comment: @Quentin I explained at last line.