# jQuery Storage: set default value if stored value is NaN

Tags: jquery, local-storage, default-value

I'm using [jQuery Storage](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/html5Storage) to save and restore a user's set volume level for a music player. Whenever they drag the volume slider, I save the value...

```
this.setVolume = function(volume) {
    ...
    $.Storage.set('volume', volume + '');
    ...
};
```

Then I use that value as the initial value for the slider the next time the page is loaded...

```
$("#volumeslider").slider({
    ...
    value: volume,
    ...
});
```

The saving and restoring part works fine. The problem is, if you're a brand new user and haven't yet adjusted the volume slider, `volume` doesn't have a value.

So I tried using a `try`/`catch` block to set the volume at `0.6` by default, unless there was a saved value to restore:

```
var volume = 0.6;
try {
    volume = parseFloat($.Storage.get('volume'));
} catch (e) { }
```

But instead, `volume` comes back as `NaN`. Then I realized that there's no "error" to catch because `NaN` is simply the result of `parseFloat` on the empty value in storage.

So: how would I set a default value only for when there's nothing in storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner solution than my original answer:

```
var volume = parseFloat($.Storage.get('volume'));
if (!volume) {
    volume = 0.6;
    $.Storage.set('volume', volume + '');
}
```

Use a stored value if it exists; if not, set a default value and store that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you storing the value as string to convert it back to a number?
Nevertheless

```
$("#volumeslider").slider({
    value: parseFloat($.Storage.get("volume") || 0.6),
});
```

Comment: According to the documentation, "Names and values should be strings. Some browsers may accept non-string values, but not all do."

Comment: @daGUY I must admit that I haven't read the documentation... Never mind me asking :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678596/nan-is-a-number) as a reference:

```
if (!isNaN(parseFloat($.Storage.get('volume')))){
    var volume = parseFloat($.Storage.get('volume'));
} else {
    var volume = 0.6;
}
```