# Map and reduce returned NAN value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to use map and reduce together to build a function where it loops through array of object and do some math but I got NAN. Why?

```js
function getTotal(){
 var obj = [
  {
    "name": "item 1",
    "discount_price": 86.9,
    "qty": 1,
  },
  {
    "name": "item 2",
    "discount_price": 11.9,
    "qty": 1,
  }
];
  
          return obj.map(function(x){;return x.discounted_price * x.qty}).reduce(function(a,b){return a + b});

 
 }

$('p').text(getTotal());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Object property is `discount_price` not `discounted_price`, since `x.discounted_price` is undefined all array values are `NaN`
([When and why number evaluates to NaN, after multiplying, in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718394/when-and-why-number-evaluates-to-nan-after-multiplying-in-javascript)).

```js
function getTotal() {
  var obj = [{
    "name": "item 1",
    "discount_price": 86.9,
    "qty": 1,
  }, {
    "name": "item 2",
    "discount_price": 11.9,
    "qty": 1,
  }];

  return obj.map(function(x) {;
    return x.discount_price * x.qty
    // -------------^------ bug is here
  }).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b
  });


}

$('p').text(getTotal());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

---

Or you can avoid the `map()` method

```js
function getTotal() {
  var obj = [{
    "name": "item 1",
    "discount_price": 86.9,
    "qty": 1,
  }, {
    "name": "item 2",
    "discount_price": 11.9,
    "qty": 1,
  }];

  return obj.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.discount_price * a.qty + b.discount_price * b.qty
  });

}

$('p').text(getTotal());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

For the problem with precision refer : [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)