# Why Math.pow(1, NaN) equals NaN in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In [**IEEE 754-2008**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) section [*"9.2.1 Special values"*](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4610935) there is mentioned that

> `pow(+1, y)` is `1` for any `y` (even a quiet `NaN`)

For not reading the entire document Wikipedia gives the [*shortcut*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Function_definition):

> The 2008 version of the IEEE 754 standard says that `pow(1, qNaN)` and
>   `pow(qNaN, 0)` should both return `1` since they return `1` whatever else is
>   used instead of quiet `NaN`.

Why then `Math.pow(1, NaN)` is `NaN` in JavaScript? Doesn't it follow the standards?

Comment: Probably it should be "pow(+1, y) is 1 for any y where y is a number", however NaN is not a number..

Comment: @ShadowWizard — [NaN is a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number) :)

Comment: @Quentin - NaN is a number, but still not a number. :)

Comment: Or you could just properly ensure that your parameters are numbers before passing them to `pow` and none of this would matter

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, but this is a *special* case which is described separately.

Comment: I noticed that, deleted my comment. I think you even missed the interesting part, because the whole line is actually: *"pow(+1, y) is 1 for any y (even a quiet NaN) "*.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, I skipped it for some reason. Added to the question with Wiki clarification as well.

Answer (score 5):

It's because [the ECMAscript specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.8.2.13) seems to say so.

> #### pow (x, y)
>
> Returns an implementation-dependent approximation to the result of raising `x` to the power `y`.
>
> - If `y` is `NaN`, the result is `NaN`.
> - ... other constraints...

Comment: Well, of course, this is the reason. So it looks like JavaScript doesn't follow the standards?

Comment: No, JavaScript follows the standards. It's the fact that even though `NaN` holds a numerical value, it does not compute as a number. Therefore, when `Math.pow(1, NaN)` is computed, it is not computed with NaN as a number.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija I didn't get your point. IEEE 754 explicitly states that `pow(1, NaN)` is *always* `1`, while ECMAscript spec states the opposite.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't particularly expect the 2009 ECMAScript specification to be taking into account the 2008 changes to the IEEE-754 specification.  Except that it does.  Looking at the bibiliography, it makes reference specifically to IEEE Std 754-2008.  So this does look like a spec miss.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754_revision#Clause_9%3a_Recommended_operations) that `pow` definition was added to IEEE 754 in 2008.  It's also optional.

On the other hand, ECMAScript's `pow` has been defined to return `NaN` if the second argument is `NaN` since at least 1997, in section 15.8.2.13 of [that year's standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf).

It would seem the ECMA committee chose to maintain compatibility with over a decade of JavaScript over complying with IEEE's peculiar new suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is because NaN is "Not a Number", some kind of a mathematical undefined. In math 1 in the power of undefined is undefined as well.

Comment: It's not some kind of undefined. `NaN == undefined` evaluates to false. :)

Comment: Your a right, I meant the math term of undefined and not JS undefined. I corrected the answer.