# Why is angular.isNumber() not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It appears as if AngularJS's `angular.isNumber` is not working. It doesn't work with strings that are numbers. Am I doing something wrong? Should I just use `isNaN()`?

```
angular.isNumber('95.55') == false
angular.isNumber('95.55' * 1) == true
angular.isNumber('bla' * 1) == true
angular.isNumber(NaN) == true
```

I need something to see if a string is a number (when it actually is) and `angular.isNumber()` won't let me do that unless I multiply by 1, but if I do that then it will always be true. Also `NaN` is not a number (by definition) and so should return false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number

Comment: What doesn't work? '95.55' is not a number, it is a string. Likewise, multiplying a string by a number will, javascript will parse/cast that string as a number and attempt do do the operation. Concatenation works differently, since number + string will be a string (javascript casts the number as a string).

Comment: @BradM I added to my question to help clarify the problem.

Comment: `angular.isObject()` doesn't return true if supplied `null` (as is the case with `typeof`), so this excuse of "that's how native javascript works" is a non-argument. And is not a justification for the ostensible dupe question status.

Comment: use like that: angular.isNumber(+num || num), if num is string/object/etc.. is preferred on NaN. so, it's actually check if the source is a number.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/504836 for a working `IsNumeric` method.

Comment: I vote this is not a duplicate of the linked question. This question is about the expected behavior of the angularJS isNumber method. It has nothing to do with whether or not NaN is considered a "number" type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In *JavaScript*, `typeof NaN === 'number'`.

If you need to recognise a *String* as a *Number*, cast it to *Number*, convert back to *String* and compare this against the input, for example.

```
function stringIsNumber(s) {
    var x = +s; // made cast obvious for demonstration
    return x.toString() === s;
}

stringIsNumber('95.55'); // true
stringIsNumber('foo'); // false
// still have
stringIsNumber('NaN'); // true
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this may suffer from rounding errors if you're dealing with extremely small or extremely large (string) numbers.

Comment: I would just add this link to an issue on angular github page, where they waived it as won't fix: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/701

Comment: WARNING: This method returns false for valid numbers like "0.0000005" since (0.0000005).toString() == "5e-7" in JavaScript.

Comment: @joelnet Hadn't considered those types of situations. Where would `+x.toString() === x` fail? You might be able to account for these edge cases

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same problem and I was trying to work around that edge case.  So I created a slightly different approach.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3eL2vanf/1/)**

```
function isStringNumber(str) {
  var parsed = parseFloat(str);
  var casted = +str;
  return parsed === casted  && !isNaN(parsed) && !isNaN(casted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as below,

```
angular.isNumber(eval('99.55'))
```

for other expressions also we may use `eval(input)`. 
*Note: `eval()` is a javascript method*

**Edit:**
It is not recommended to use `eval()`, as document says [Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

Thanks @Diogo Kollross

Comment: Using `eval()` is [insanely insecure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!).