# AngularJS says 1+1 is 11

Tags: angularjs, math

I have a issue with AngularJS and very basic math.  When I have picked the data from my firebase, I want to addition them.

Here's my code:

```
  $scope.project.$on('loaded', function(value) {
  console.log(value); // data loaded from Firebase
  console.log(value.name); // subset of the returned value

  angular.isNumber(value.firstmatch);
  angular.isNumber(value.secondmatch);



  $scope.project.points = ((value.firstmatch) + (value.firstmatch));
```

And this outputs 11. And yes, the firstmatch value is 1.

Thanks!

Comment: Adding in this case is being interpreted as string concatenation, not number addition: '1' + '1' = '11'.

Comment: [This can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351831/why-is-angular-isnumber-not-working-as-expected), look at the comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your data is giving you strings, just convert them to numbers:

```
 $scope.project.$on('loaded', function(value) {
  console.log(value); // data loaded from Firebase
  console.log(value.name); // subset of the returned value

  //angular.isNumber(value.firstmatch);
  //angular.isNumber(value.secondmatch);



  $scope.project.points = parseInt(value.firstmatch, 10) + parseInt(value.firstmatch,10);
```