# How to bind input value to $scope object in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS and I want to bind the input value to $scope object, just like we use **ng-bind** and **ng-model** for input fields to bind their values to DOM (the value changes as we type something in the input).

Can't I do the same? I mean just like displaying live text entered into input should be stored to **$scope.foo.bar** and hence it is printed in the **console**?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
    app.service("stringService", function(){
        this.myFunction = function(word){
            return word.toUpperCase();
        };
    });
    app.controller("control", function($scope, $location, stringService, $http){
        $scope.age=24;
        $scope.foo = {bar: "hello"};
        console.log($scope.foo.bar);
        $scope.isNumber = angular.isNumber($scope.foo.bar);
    });

</script>

<div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="control" ng-init="obj=[{name:'vikas'}, {name: 'vijay'}, {name: 'vinay'}]; mySwitch=true">
        <form name="testForm">
            <input type="text" name="bar" ng-model="foo.bar" required>
        </form>
        <div>{{isNumber}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can see the initial value (hello) in the console and **false** in DOM. But it doesn't update.

Comment: Is there any other code which might be modifying foo?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line `$scope.isNumber = angular.isNumber($scope.foo.bar);` will only run once which is at angular initialize the page.

you can change `isNumber` to function in order to call multiple times.

```
$scope.isNumber = function() {
  return angular.isNumber($scope.foo.bar);
}
```

call it at template:

```
<div>{{isNumber()}}</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.service("stringService", function() {
  this.myFunction = function(word) {
    return word.toUpperCase();
  };
});
app.controller("control", function($scope, $location, stringService, $http) {
  $scope.age = 24;
  $scope.foo = {
    bar: 1
  };
  console.log($scope.foo.bar);
  $scope.isNumber = function() {
    console.log(Number.isFinite($scope.foo.bar));
    console.log(typeof($scope.foo.bar));
    return angular.isNumber($scope.foo.bar);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="control" ng-init="obj=[{name:'vikas'}, {name: 'vijay'}, {name: 'vinay'}]; mySwitch=true">
    <form name="testForm">
      <input type="text" name="bar" ng-model="foo.bar" required>
    </form>
    <div>{{isNumber()}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "this line `$scope.isNumber = angular.isNumber($scope.foo.bar);` will only run once". `isNumber()` would also fire only once? Do I need to use `ng-change` like Parth suggested?

Comment: @VikasKumar no, if you bind function in template, it will be fired every time in angular's digest cycle.

Comment: Just tried. It doesn't. Just shows output for initial value.

Comment: Further it is showing false for every possible value, even for a string :O

Comment: Okay. The function fires every time I change it. But it returns false even for a number after I change initial value?

Comment: Maybe because I've already assigned `bar: 'sdf'` ? It appends this string with next input? Do I need to empty this key first?

Comment: @VikasKumar no, that won't help. when you assign `input` with type `text`, it will turn to string when value changed.

Comment: Oh. So I need `parseInt()` ?

Comment: @VikasKumar why not just assign `input` to `number` type and save the check part?

Comment: You're right but I'm new to it and just want to learn things :) Secondly I did parseInt but it returned `true` for everything now. Which is maybe  `isNumber` returns `true` even for `NaN`. What say?

Comment: @VikasKumar see here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isNumber   actually it is.

Comment: @VikasKumar also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351831/why-is-angular-isnumber-not-working-as-expected will clear your confusion. :-)

Comment: @VikasKumar it should be `Number.isFinite()` :-)

Comment: Oh. It's JS function that's why it showed error. Thanks a lot. I got what I needed. I just did `isFinite(24)` and worked.

Answer (score 1):

while @Pengyy's is quite correct in saying that you need to databind to a function, that is only part of the problem...

The problem is `NaN`, a perplexing numeric value that is not a number, but has type `'number'` and some quicks having to do with bindings to string valued attributes like `<input>`'s `value` in html.

```js
// the constant NaN
console.info(NaN);
// the type of the constant NaN
console.info(typeof NaN);
// NaN is not equal to NaN 
console.info(NaN === NaN);
// Number.isNaN checks for NaN
console.info(Number.isNaN(NaN));
// Number.isNaN returns false for any value unless typeof value === 'number'
console.info(Number.isNaN({
  a: []
}));
```

surprisingly, Angular's `angular.isNumber` function does not help us deal with these oddities. As stated in the documentation it

> Determines if a reference is a Number.
>   This includes the "special" numbers NaN, +Infinity and -Infinity.
>   If you wish to exclude these then you can use the native `isFinite' method.

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isNumber

To make matters worse, it also ignores all values for which `typeof value !== 'number'`

Finally, the last hurdle to overcome is that an HTML input's value is always a `string`! This means we need to convert it to number.

Therefore, the function needs to look like

```
$scope.isNumber = function(n) {
  // must convert to number because `Number.isNaN` does not coerce
  return isFinite(n) && !Number.isNaN(Number(n));
}
```

And the binding like

```
<div>{{isNumber(foo.bar)}}</div>
```

Here is an example

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular
      .module("testApp", [])
      .controller({
        MyController
      });

    MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function MyController($scope) {
      $scope.foo = {
        bar: "hello"
      };
      console.log($scope.foo.bar);
      $scope.isNumber = function(n) {
        console.info(typeof n);
        return isFinite(n) && angular.isNumber(Number(n));
      }
    }
  }());
</script>

<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <form name="testForm">
      <input type="type" name="bar" ng-model="foo.bar" required>
    </form>
    <div>{{isNumber(foo.bar)}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how the raw type of the input is always `'string'`

Answer (score 0):

Value must be updating but you do not have anything to communicate, You need a watcher or a function that fires the console log and checks for number.

Change your controller to  :-

```
 app.controller("control", function($scope, $location, stringService, $http){
            $scope.age=24;
            $scope.foo = {bar: "hello"};
            console.log($scope.foo.bar);
            $scope.isNumber = angular.isNumber($scope.foo.bar);
            $scope.check = function() {
                $scope.isNumber =  angular.isNumber($scope.foo.bar);
                console.log($scope.foo.bar);
                console.log($scope.isNumber);
            }
        });
```

And in Html

```
<input type="type" name="bar" ng-model="foo.bar" ng-change="check()" required>
```