# typeof("2px" - 1 ) returns number and "2px" - 1 returns NaN. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says it all. Why does `typeof("2px" - 1)` return `number` and `"2px" - 1` return `NaN`?

Comment: Because javascript's data typing was written on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: Because `typeof NaN` *is* `"number"`. See [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.20).

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2801617/44853) has your answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that is a funny comment.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov I would have marked this as a duplicate except the second half of that question deviates from its title and what this is asking, and the accepted answer actually does not answer this question (the answer I linked to in an earlier comment though does)

Comment: @Ic. So there is a similar question and a good answer for it already. It should be closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `NaN` is of type `number`.

`number` in javascript is a IEEE-754 double ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)) and `NaN` is a special value of that data type. As such, the result is consistant.

The real question should be: why does `"2px"-1` result in `NaN`? Javascript first converts the string into a number, using `Number("2px")`, which results in `NaN`, as it is not a parseable number. Any other operation on `NaN` results in `NaN` as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: There isn't really anything to elaborate on.

Answer (score 3):

"2px"-1 is the number `NaN`.

NaN stands for not-a-number, the result for operations like dividing 0 by 0 or taking the square root of -1. And also for illegal conversions like this.