# How to check if function has a parameter and if it's number

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am new to unitTesting and using Mocha/Chai. I am trying to test if the function has a parameter and if it's a number.

```
// Main Function
function Sh(partnerUserId) {


  function validPartnerId(partnerUserId) {
    if (!partnerUserId);
    throw new Error("Missing partnerId");


    if (isNaN(partnerUserId));
    throw new Error("Not a number");

    return true;
  }
}



// Unit Test

var expect = chai.expect;

describe("Sh", function() {

    it('should check if the partnerId is provided', function(){
        ????
    });


    it('should check if the partnerId is a number', function(){
       ????
    });

});
```

I am open to suggestions if there is a better way to do it. I am trying to find how to capture the value of an argument and validate it in unit testing.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion guys. I am talking about the unit testing. I go the js code, I need help with unit test.

Comment: Your function will not work as intended if you pass `0`

Answer (score 2):

It is really not clear what you are going for with your `Sohalo` function. I've had to rewrite it to get a function that makes sense. At any rate, what you need to use to check whether the checks are happening is `expect(fn).to.throw(...)`. The documentation for it is [here](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#throw). Note that when you want to check that a call with specific arguments throws an exception, the convenient way to do it is using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). So something like:

```
expect(Sohalo.bind(undefined, 1)).to.not.throw(Error, "Not a number");
```

will test the call `Sohalo(1)`. (The first argument to `bind` sets the value of `this` inside the function, and we don't need it here so I'm leaving it `undefined`).

So a file that would contain your function and test it could look something like this:

```
function Sohalo(partnerUserId) {
    if (typeof partnerUserId !== "number" || isNaN(partnerUserId))
        throw new Error("Not a number");
}

var chai = require("chai");
var expect = chai.expect;

describe("Sohalo", function() {
    it('should fail if partnerUserId is not given', function(){
        // This tests calling Sohalo with no arguments whatsoever.
        expect(Sohalo).to.throw(Error, "Not a number");
    });

    it('should fail if partnerUserId is not a number', function(){
        expect(Sohalo.bind(undefined, {})).to.throw(Error, "Not a number");
    });

    it('should fail if partnerUserId is NaN', function(){
        expect(Sohalo.bind(undefined, NaN)).to.throw(Error, "Not a number");
    });

    it('should not fail if the partnerUserId is a literal number', function(){
        expect(Sohalo.bind(undefined, 1)).to.not.throw(Error, "Not a number");
    });

    it('should not fail if the partnerUserId is a Number object', function(){
        expect(Sohalo.bind(undefined, Number(10))).to.not.throw(Error, "Not a number");
    });
});
```

In my test suites, I would typically perform tests with `expect().to.throw` but not with `expect().to.not.throw`. Instead of explicitly checking that the function does not throw, I'd just call it with good arguments and check that the results are correct. I'm using `expect().to.not.throw` here only for the sake of illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
function isNumber(x) {
  return typeof x === 'number';
}
```

then, somewhere else you can use the `isNumber` function to determine if `x` is a number, and react accordingly:

```
function Sohalo (partnerUserId) {
  if (!isNumber(partnerUserId)) {
    // if it's not a number, throw exception
    throw new Error('partnerUserId needs to be a number!');
  }
  // ... do other stuff down here ...
}
```

---

Unit Test Suggestions:

Create an object like this:

```
var sohalo = (function () {
  var me = {},
      id;

  function isNumber(x) {
    return typeof x === 'number';
  }

  function isDefined(x) {
    return typeof value !== 'undefined';
  }

  me.validatePartnerId = function () {
    return isDefined(id) && isNumber(id);
  }

  me.setPartnerId = function (newId) {
    id = newId;
  };
  me.getPartnerId = function () {
    return id;
  };

  return me;
})();


describe('sohalo', function () {

  it('should check if the partner id is provided', function () {
    var id = sohalo.getPartnerId();
    id.should.equal(undefined);
  });

  it('should check if the partner id is a number', function () {
    sohalo.setPartnerId(5);
    sohalo.validatePartnerId().should.equal(true);
    sohalo.setPartnerId('5');
    sohalo.validatePartnerId().should.equal(false);    
  });
});
```

Here is a post I found that gives a little example: https://gist.github.com/michaelcox/3800736.

Hope this helps

Comment: This will fail if the user passes in `NaN`.

Comment: @JuanMendes Well, actually, despite the fact that NaN stands for 'Not-A-Number', it actually just means a value that cannot be specified within the limitation of the numeric type (for instance divide by 0). The actual `typeof NaN` returns 'number'. So, it is in fact of type `number`. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number. All this said, it depends on how you want things implemented. If you don't want `NaN` returning true for number type check, then add an extra check for this.

Comment: Yes, since `typeof NaN` is `'number'`, the OP would want that to fail, which your code won't do.` It will also fail if you pass in `Number(5)` but it shouldn't?

Comment: Hmm, well when I run it the way you described, it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/P21tSJ2QL3zEbzhA2G1P?p=preview. Also, not sure why you would ever need to wrap a primitive in its object type like that..

Comment: I meant `new Number(2)` http://plnkr.co/edit/ToLOQ05sR9kG690NAzqG?p=preview . There's no good reason to do it, but it's possible that some code may do it, so you should prevent against it, the OP is trying to be extra defensive

Comment: Well, first of all, you should never use the `Number` constructor directly like that. But, if you did, things still work. The reason the `isNumber` function returns false for this is because calling `new Number(2)` is actually creating a Number `object` (of type `Object`), so `isNumber` is still returning the correct result. That is, detecting whether a variable `x` is `typeof` number.

Comment: But a function that expects a number primitive should work if it gets a `Number` object, you should not throw an error just because someone boxed it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60026/discussion-between-pje-and-juan-mendes).