# Why typeof acts differently if assigned?

Tags: javascript, nan, typeof

Why are these different?

```
typeof 0/0 === 'number' // returns false
```

while

```
value = typeof 0/0;
typeof value === 'number';  // returns true
```

Thanks!!

Comment: First seems to eval as `(typeof 0)/0` so it's `NaN` and not equal to `'number'`. Second is `typeof NaN` and you get `'number'`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number

Comment: Thanks. The reason one is false while the other is true is because of the order of operation (like fuyushimoya wrote).