# Why is NaN value outputted?

Tags: javascript, nan

I'm trying to solver [Project Euler #8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8). It asks to find the largest product of 13 consecutive digits in the following 1000-digit number. Here is my code (in JavaScript):

```
var bigNumber = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
for(var i = 0, largest = 0; i < 987; i++) {
  for(var j = 0, product = 1; j < 13; j++)
    product *= parseInt(bigNumber.substring(i*13+j, i*13+j+1));
  largest = Math.max(largest, product);
}
```

The answer is stored in `largest`. For some reason, `largest` is `NaN`, and I do not know why.

I've checked all the data types of all the numbers, especially `product` and `largest`, and they always turn up as "number." Their values are never infinity, which may [also cause a NaN value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2801629/2397327).

I was also thinking maybe the products might be too large JavaScript to handle, but I thought it might have thrown a specific error for that.

What is causing this error and how should I solve it?

Comment: Not that this is a bad question but did you try debugging this at all? console.log() maybe? Math with `Infinity` tends to produce `NaN` is more the issue.

Comment: @djechlin I did use `console.log()` (quite extensively too). And I didn't know that Infinity returns NaN-- if so, then it is almost definitely the problem.

Comment: Look, you have i upto 987, and then i * 13, which is 12K+ - far longer than your string.

Comment: OK so please post what largest was right before it became NaN.

Comment: @djechlin It was 6270566400, the 13 numbers starting at index 76.

Comment: OK, can you turn it into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) now?

Comment: @djechlin What do you mean? It is runnable now, correct?

Comment: It's not the shortest program possible. It sounds like you have the exact loop iteration that is blowing up. You could post just that iteration. Right now you have over a kilobyte of code in your post.

Comment: FTR I still don't know how you got NaN from a finite number instead of Infinity. So this is exactly how you debug it (short of using a debugger).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `console.log(parseInt(bigNumber.substring(i*13+j, i*13+j+1)));` you will see that it will print `NaN`.

The problem is that your substring is out of bounds.

Comment: I didn't realize that this was the problem: I hadn't considered that the `i*13` was way out of bounds and should have been just `i`. Oops.

Comment: I see what you were trying to do, but yeah, it was way out of bounds ;) `console.log(i*13+j, bigNumber.length)` would show that too.

Answer (score 0):

> I was also thinking maybe the products might be too large JavaScript to handle, but I thought it might have thrown a specific error for that.

Really? It would be *very* strange to me for a language to support `Infinity` and throw an error instead of use it.

There's some simple ways to test this for yourself:

```
for (var i = 0; ; i = i*2) console.log(i); // will eventually print Infinity
```

(Plus actual documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

The NaN problem is due to the way you are calculating which character you need to parseInt on. If you modify the code and keep a watch on largest, you'll see it takes on a value of Infinity, rather than NaN:

```
var bigNumber = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
var largest = 0;
var product = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 999; i++) {

  for (var j = 0; j < 13; j++) {

    //Your original code produces NaN error:
    product *= parseInt(bigNumber.substring(i * 13 + j, i * 13 + j + 1));

    // This (more simple code) produces Infinity:
    product *= parseInt(bigNumber.charAt(j));
  }

  largest = Math.max(largest, product);

}
```