# JavaScript: How to circumvent the typeof NaN issue?

Tags: javascript, typeof

```
console.log(typeof NaN)
```

The above returns 'number'.

**Q1.** How do I find a way around this?

**Q2.** What is a better way to find the type of a variable? (instead of `typeof`)

Thanks!

**Update:**
Thank you for all your comments. But the first answerer understood my question. I was concerned about assessing the type of a return statement of 'NaN' to not show up as a 'Number'.

I was using typeof() in an if statement to act when if(typeof(x) == "number") { do this.. }

But the condition passed even though x was NaN. I wanted to resolve this.

I did not know 'NaN' was of type 'Number' cause NaN means 'Not a Number'. That led to confusion.

I apologize for not being clear on what I wanted to ask. But my issue is solved.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Q1. way around what? typeof returning what the spec says it will? 2. what's wrong with using typeof?

Comment: `NaN` is a number type. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Related: [Why does typeof NaN return 'number'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number)

Comment: @Sunny - According to the spec.  NaN is of type Number.  But the method above will fail for both null and arrays.  See my answer below.

Comment: Why would `typeof NaN` *not* be 'number'?

Comment: @MarkReed to be fair it does stand for "Not a number," which would seem to preclude it being a number.

Comment: Point.  Its not-a-number-ness applies to its value rather than its type, but I can understand the confusion.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Don't use typeof unless speed is a need it fails for both arrays and null.  However according to the spec NaN is in fact of type Number.

Use

```
var getType = function (obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
};
```

Comment: Reference error: Pub is not defined.

Comment: And also: what? Seems to return typeof only with the first letter capitalized. Including Nan --> "Number" which seems to be the OP's complaint. And it internally calls typeof I'm pretty sure. This isn't "better" in any way.

Comment: This is from a library.  I've edited it for you to use stand alone.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my issue. This solves it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a number is not NaN, you may want to use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function:

```
var val = 4

console.log(isNaN(val)) // false

var val2 = NaN

console.log(isNaN(val2)) // true
```

To check whether a variable contains a number and is not NaN You may then use the following:

```
typeof val === 'number' && !isNAN(val)
```

Comment: But be advised that `isNaN(undefined)` is `true`.

Comment: This helps too. Thank you!