# Why is "string" - "string" NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan, typeof

This is something like an infinite loop for me.

```
var sM = "Hello" - "World";
console.log(sM) && console.log(typeof sM);
```

I understand why string -  string outputs NaN, but then `"Hello" - "World"` `typeof` is a `number`.

It means subtracting string with another string gives you a type of a `number`.

Where is the logic in that?

Comment: [jQuery.isNumeric](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) does return false for NaN values. typeof only returns the internal storage mechanism for that particular variable type. In this case its stored as a number, specifically a float stored according to IEEE 754 to correspond to NaN

Comment: Why would it be a number?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> why string - string outputs NaN

Because subtraction only deals in numbers, so it converts both sides to numbers and gets *Not A Number*.

> but then "Hello" - "World" typeof is a number.

`NaN` has the type *Number*. [This is standard in computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number).

Comment: Oh, so when you subtract two strings because of mathematical operation, the type changes, but since you of course cannot subtract strings with another strings it outputs as "Not a Number".

Comment: Depends on the strings. `"12" - "10" === 2`

Comment: So only if we use words-only in a strings?

Comment: @Super11 only if `Number(yourString)` is `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

Because `typeof NaN` is `number`.

It makes sense that you can't subtract 2 strings, so their subtraction is not a number (`NaN`).

What probably doesn't make as much sense is why `NaN` (not a number) is of type `number`. :)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number) for more details about the part that makes less sense.

Comment: Also because adding a mathematical operator `-` converts whatever follows into a number?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is just one between many cases where javascripts operations produce results that may be unexpected to the newcomer. This happens because of implicit type coersion. Which is a type change in values that occurs automatically in certain operations where different types are involved or expected.
These cases are thoroughly described in this chapter from one of the You Don't Know Js free books, here:

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20&%20grammar/ch4.md

I definitively recommend this book series to every JS developer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, up voted.

Comment: this and many other JS resources are in SO javascript tag info, here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info