# Why does Number.isNaN() return false for Strings?

Tags: javascript, nan

As per my understanding `NaN` stands for `Not A Number`. **Strings** are not definitely **Numbers** and hence I expect the below code to return `true` for Strings. However, it's not the case.

```js
console.log(Number.isNaN("Stack Overflow"));
```

Could somebody please clarify this?

Comment: `NaN` is actually a value.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Comment: `Number.isNaN` only returns true if its argument is `NaN`. It seems weird, but the reason for its existence is falsiness of `NaN === NaN` expression.

Comment: console.log(isNaN("Stack Overflow"));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does typeof NaN return 'number'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a distinction to be made between `Number.isNaN` and `isNaN`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

> The isNaN() function determines whether a value is NaN or not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

> The Number.isNaN() method determines whether the passed value is NaN and its type is Number. It is a more robust version of the original, global isNaN().

The reason you are returning false is that "Stack Overflow" is not a number it is a string.

```js
console.log('Number.isNaN("Stack Overflow"): '+Number.isNaN("Stack Overflow"));
console.log('isNaN("Stack Overflow"): '+isNaN("Stack Overflow"));
```

Comment: The more I think about this the more I think it is confusing!

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN#Description

> In comparison to the global isNaN() function, Number.isNaN() doesn't
>   suffer the problem of forcefully converting the parameter to a number.
>   This means it is now safe to pass values that would normally convert
>   to NaN, but aren't actually the same value as NaN. This also means
>   that **only values of the type number, that are also NaN, return true**.

Answer (score 1):

This returns true:

`console.log(isNaN("Stack Overflow"));`

Whereas this returns false:

`console.log(Number.isNaN("Stack Overflow"));`

Answer (score 0):

It's not Number.isNaN.

```js
console.log(isNaN("Stack Overflow"));
```

Comment: But there IS [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj yes but it does something different

Comment: @AndrewBone yes but the answer should instead explain the difference. Or that though it's there, this case should use `isNaN()`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj if you want to know more about Number.isNaN, please follow the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Comment: @Shiladitya Is this the same link that I posted in my first comment? What I meant was your answer could be more useful if you had added the difference between the two. Currently, it's just plainly wrong when it says `It's not Number.isNan`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this

```
Number.isNaN(Number("Stack Overflow")) // returns true
Number.isNaN(Number(false)) // returns false (unfortunately)
Number.isNaN(Number(12)) // returns false
Number.isNaN(Number(12.02)) // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems weird but once understood that NaN means "Not a Number" in a strict sense described here [Why does typeof NaN return 'number'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2801629/1163543) (division by zero, etc), this is what I use:

```
typeof value === "number" && !isNaN(value)
```

Comment: Thanks @dgolive. I was a novice at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add something here which makes it somewhat clear for me.

For my purposes there's a distinction between 'not a number' and Nan.

- 'not a number' could be any other primitive type that is not a number.
- NaN is the numeric value Number.NaN.

console.log(isNaN("StackOverflow")); => true as it ONLY checks if the value is 'not a number'

console.log(isNaN("3")); => false as isNaN does a conversion before checking if the input is 'not a number'

If a = NaN and b = Number.NaN.

> All a are b, but not all b are a.

We would only get Number.IsNaN() = true (as all a are b we will also have IsNan() = true for these cases) in specific cases:

1. Where a conversion fails: parseInt("a");
2. Where we perform a mathematical operation which does not return a real number: Math.sqrt(-1);
3. Indeterminite form (0 * Infinity)
4. Where we use Nan as an operand: 7 * NaN (NaN is contageous!)
5. Where we want to represent an invalid value as a number: new Date("a").getTime();

Answer (score -1):

try that:

```js
console.log(isNaN("Stack Overflow"));
```

Answer (score -2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), non-numeric values are first coerced to a number, and then tested for NaN. So, empty string (`""`) in JS is considered falsy, and so is converted to 0, which is definitely a number.