# Javascript typeof and IsNaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, polyfills

In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) polyfill function for `Array.prototype.includes()`, I found the following code.

```
function sameValueZero(x, y) {
    return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
}
```

In the above code 
`typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y)` this makes me confusing. If the `typeof` the variable is a number , `isNaN` will be always false right? so when this whole condition will return true? Can someone explain or did I understand it wrongly?

Comment: x = Number(NaN) - x is type number & isNaN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does typeof NaN return 'number'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, the type of `NaN` is `number`. I guess this is because it is the result of mathematical operations.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This code will return `true` if the 2 elements are `NaN`, but `false` if the both are not numbers.

As you can see, the 1st example returns `true` is both `isNaN()` regardless of their type - which makes `a` equal `b`. The 2nd checks if both are numbers before using `isNaN()`:

```js
const checkEq1 = (x, y) => isNaN(x) && isNaN(y)

console.log(checkEq1(NaN, NaN)); // true

console.log(checkEq1('a', 'b')); // true - error

const checkEq2 = (x, y) => typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y)

console.log(checkEq2(NaN, NaN)); // true

console.log(checkEq2('a', 'b')); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if `typeof x === 'number'`, `x` can be `NaN`, and then `isNaN(x) && typeof x === 'number'` will both be `true`.

No idea why that function just doesn't use `Number.isNaN(x) && Number.isNaN(y)` though, since that will explicitly check if the value is `NaN` (as opposed to anything that can be `NaN` when converted to a number, as with `isNaN`).