# Why does Number.parseInt('111AAA') works like its supposed to in JS ? What is the reasoning behind this behaviour?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017, ecma

If I execute `parseInt('111AAA')` we get the output `'111'`. In javascript why does parseInt work as its mentioned in the MDN docs.

> The parseInt function converts its first argument to a string, parses
> it, and returns an integer or NaN. If not NaN, the returned value will
> be the decimal integer representation of the first argument taken as a
> number in the specified radix (base). For example, a radix of 10
> indicates to convert from a decimal number, 8 octal, 16 hexadecimal,
> and so on. For radices above 10, the letters of the alphabet indicate
> numerals greater than 9. For example, for hexadecimal numbers (base
> 16), A through F are used.
>
> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
> specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
> returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates
> numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

I've started to pick up JS and have a background working in Java and C. Shouldn't it be giving error if an alphanumeric value is supplied to it. What is the reasoning behind this behaviour ? Is there any other language that adopts this ?

Edit: Its been pointed out that similar functionality exists in C by @jabaa
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: _"Is there any other language that adopts this ?"_ Yes, C, C++ and probably many others ;-) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol See the example with `"31337 with words"`. It's parsed to `31337`. Most "weird" things about JavaScript I've read on Stack Overflow are very common in many other programming languages.

Comment: Welcome to Javascript. your question is a bit weird, why is it working as described on the docs? why would it not?

Comment: [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio)

Comment: *Shouldn't it be giving error if an alphanumeric value is supplied to it.* Why would you parse it in the first place, if that was the case?

Comment: If you want a more strict version use `Number('111AAA')`, this will return `NaN`..

Comment: @monaxs I raised this question because there was a really good answer to one of my queries about NaN. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801601/why-does-typeof-nan-return-number . Similarly I was searching for an answer like that regarding my question.

Comment: "Why does <x feature> work like it's supposed to" do you... do you expect it *not* to? I don't see why one would expect something not to work the way it is intended in a language.

Answer (score 4):

As the name suggests, `parseInt` as a parser, not a converter. While a converter takes a string as a whole and tries to make sense of it, a parser consumes the input symbol by symbol and stops at the first symbol it cannot process. In javascript, the converter for numbers is `Number`:

```js
console.log(Number('123foo'))
console.log(parseInt('123foo'))
```

In C, `atoi`, `strtol` and similar functions are all parsers, not converters.